# Acceder a un input hidden que está en una master page desde un web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice

Tengo una master page que uso en todo mi sitio. En ella, tengo varios controles html input hidden para mantener valores que son usados de forma transversal. Quiero acceder (leer y escribir) a los valores de estos controles desde un web service.

La semántica usada en los tags de estos input es la siguiente:

```
<input type="hidden" id="Renueva_Sess" runat="server" class="input_oculto" />
```

¿Alguna sugerencia? Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var txt = $("<%=Txt.ClientID%>");
var dataSend = "{codigo:'" + txt.get_textBoxValue() + "'}";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    url: '../WS/Test.asmx/GetData',
    dataType: "json",
    data: dataSend,
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.d.Success == true) {
            var txt = document.getElementById("<%=HddUrl.ClientID%>");
            if (txt != null) {
                var representante = JSON.parse(data.d.Message);
                if (representante != null) {
                    txt.value = representante.Nombre;
                } else {
                    txt.value = 'SIN DATOS';
                }
            }
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert(data.responseText);
    }
});
```

Mas o menos esta es la idea. Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Muy amable. Ya tengo el ajax y tengo el web service. Lo que deseo saber es como desde el web service se leen (escriben) los input hidden que están en una master page.

Comment: $('#<%=Master.FindControl("Renueva_Sess").ClientID%>').val('test');

Comment: De nuevo muy gentil. Dado que este código es jquery es para implementar en el aspx (plantilla master) verdad?. Yo debo implementar la solución en c# en el cuerpo del web service.

Comment: Puedes implementarlo en una pagina hija en el content y de ahí llamar a los controles que contiene la master page.